# Codeigniter CI_SESSIONS expire on window closed not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have searched a lot for this topic and can't find working solution as i need.
I am using ci_sessions to store users data on db, bt when i close window and not logout then after some hours i login again then my previous session also stores in db and new session also create so duplicate session create. I also use this property

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
```

but it doesn't work. I want to destroy session when browsers get closed. I am using CI latest version.

Comment: what version you are using

Comment: i'm using CI Version 2.12 and it's working fine. Session expire on close browser.

_i'm bad English, sorry_

Comment: i am also usnig ci 2.12 verssion bt it not expire when browser close ..:(

Answer (score 0):

You can set `cookie` for this which will expire on browser close event and you can check in your website that if `cookie` doesn't exists then destroy the session.

Set `cookie` like this :

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", '');
```

If you will not define the cookie destroy time then it will get destroyed as soon as browser gets closed so it will help you.

Comment: I am usnig ci_sessions table to store and using it so i want to remove from this not from using cookie.

Comment: So you can check that if cookie doesn't exists then from the previous session id you can delete data from database and destroy that session and start a new session so you won't have duplicate sessions.

Comment: can u tell me clearly how to do it, in config file i have defined cookie name is 
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
then how to setcokkie and where to set it to achive me goal

Comment: You can set your cookie in the same file just where you are setting session and this cookie will not be on this name $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session'. It will be a different named cookie.